# How to work out $\frac{1}{1+t^{2}} = 1 - t^{2} + t^{4} - t^{6} + \dots$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, divisibility

I'm working on trying to find the taylor polynomial expansion for $\arctan(x)$. I'm doing this working through *Spivak's Calculus* pg 414. In it we are attempting to rewrite:

$$ \frac{1}{1+t^{2}} = 1 - t^{2} + t^{4} - t^{6} + \dots + (-1)^{n}t^{2n} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}t^{2n+2}}{1 + t^{2}}$$

Right now I'm attempting to work out the pattern for the first few terms. But I'm having trouble with the long division
$$\require{enclose} 
\begin{array}{r}
t^2+1 \enclose{longdiv}{1}\\
\end{array}$$
Could I get a hint or reference on how to treat this type of expression? I know how to do the easier long division expressions such as
$$\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
t^2+1 \enclose{longdiv}{t^{3} + t^{2} + 3}\\
\end{array}$$ as an example. But this one is tripping me up.

Comment: Do you know that $\dfrac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$?

Comment: This long division thing is holding you back. The first few cases of the identity are $$\frac1{1+t^2}=1-\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$\frac1{1+t^2}=1-t^2+\frac{t^4}{1+t^2}$$
$$\frac1{1+t^2}=1-t^2+t^4-\frac{t^6}{1+t^2}$$ Can you see how to go from each one to the next?

Comment: @AnginaSeng, that's a whole lot of adding zeros to the expression, but I do see where to carry on from here. Out of curiosity where did such an idea emerge from to write it in this way?....Thanks for your help

Comment: Also why not include the odd numbered terms?

Comment: Have you seen the formula for the sum of a geometric series? That's all this is, with first term $1$ and common ratio $-t^2$.

Comment: @Ned, that makes sense. I do find it odd though because geometric series are not treated until after this chapter so technically "I don't know" about them...

Comment: @AnginaSeng I got most of it, but I'm having trouble extracting the final remainder term from this pattern.

Comment: @dc3rd  Take the right side of the equation at the top and multiply it by $1 + t^2$. Distribute carefully -- it will telescope down to $1$. Hence, the original right side equals $1 / (1 + t^2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unclear whether the OP has grasped the offered answers (e.g. Pendronator's answer).

My answer, will use the idea from Pendronator's answer and provide more detail. 
Hopefully, this will remove the OP's confusion (if any).

Assume that $|x| < 1.\;$ 
$[E_1]\;$ This implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0.$

Consider the equation 
$( 1 - x) \times (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n) \;=\; 1 - x^{(n+1)}.$

This means that for any **fixed** positive integer $n,$ 
$\frac{1 - x^{(n+1)}}{1 - x} \;=\; (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n).$

However, $\frac{1 - x^{(n+1)}}{1 - x} \;=\; \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{x^{(n+1)}}{1 - x}.$ 
This means that the **error** in approximating $\frac{1}{1-x}$ by 
$(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n)$ will be 
$\frac{x^{(n+1)}}{1 - x}.$

Now use $E_1$ to consider what happens to the **error** 
when $n \to \infty.$ 
It should be immediate to the OP that as $n \to \infty$, the error goes to 0.

To the OP:
**This is a critical point.** If this is unclear to you, please respond to this answer with
a comment.

Another possible point of confusion is syntax.
$(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots)$ is used to **represent** 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n).$

This means that the equation 
$[E_2] \;\frac{1}{1-x} \;=\; (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots)$ 
actually (somewhat informally) represents the equation 
$\frac{1}{1-x} \;=\; \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n).$

The equation immediately above is **true only because** (as shown by the analysis
in this answer), the corresponding error term goes to 0 as $n \to \infty.$

Assuming that the OP now accepts equation $E_2$ above, then I recommend that the
OP re-examine Pedronator's answer.

**Addendum** Response to dc3rd's subsequent comment

To the OP: 
Please respond with a comment after you read this addenum, re 
have I totally resolved your confusion.
**Also**, to keep the webpage *tidy*, let us both delete (now obsolete) comments
that follow this answer.

First of all the analysis in Angina Seng's comment can be **bypassed** by simply 
**very closely scrutinizing** Pedronator's answer (assuming that you understand and
completely agree with my answer.

As a preliminary step in resolving your confusion, I definitely advocate that you
re-examine Pedronator's answer.

For your clarity however, I'm going to hijack the idea directly from Angina Seng's comment
and simply express it differently.

Consider the equation 
$[F_1]\; (1 + t^2) \times [1 - t^2 + t^4 - t^6 + \cdots - \cdots + (-1)^n t^{(2n)}]
\;=\; 1 + (-1)^n t^{(2n+2)},$ 
which holds for any positive integer $n.$

**Before going further:** you should manually verify that equation $F_1$ holds.

Using $F_1$, this means that for any **fixed** positive integer $n,$ 
$[F_2]\; \frac{1 + (-1)^n t^{(2n+2)}}{1 + t^2}
\;=\; [1 - t^2 + t^4 - t^6 + \cdots - \cdots + (-1)^n t^{(2n)}].$

However, $\frac{1 + (-1)^n t^{(2n+2)}}{1 + t^2} \;=\;
\frac{1}{1 + t^2} + \frac{(-1)^n t^{(2n+2)}}{1 + t^2}.$

$[F_3]$ 
This means that the **error** in approximating $\frac{1}{1 + t^2}$ by 
$[1 - t^2 + t^4 - t^6 + \cdots - \cdots + (-1)^n t^{(2n)}]$ will be 
$\frac{(-1)^n t^{(2n+2)}}{1 + t^2}.$

The remainder of this analysis very closely parallels the analysis in my original
answer.  That is, 
whenever $|t|$ < 1, the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(t^2\right)^n \;=\; 0.$

Thus, as $n \to \infty$, the error term in $F_3$ goes to 0. 
Therefore, $\frac{1}{1 + t^2} \;=\;
\lim_{n \to \infty} [1 - t^2 + t^4 - t^6 + \cdots - \cdots + (-1)^n t^{(2n)}].$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$$ for all $\left| x\right| <1$. Substituting $x=-t^2$, $$\frac{1}{1-(-t^2)}=\frac{1}{1+t^2}=1-t^2+t^4-\cdots$$ for all $\left|-t^2 \right|=t^2 <1$, assuming $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                \phantom{10}&&\color{purple}1\color{blue}{-x}+x^2\cdots  \\[-3pt]
&1+x\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\enclose{longdiv}{1} \\[-3pt]
     &\underline{\color{purple}{1+x}}\phantom{2} \\[-3pt]
      &          -x  \\[-3pt]
     &\underline{\color{blue}{-x-x^2}}\\
&x^2\\
&...
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Please edit to improve alignment

Comment: I'm trying to follow but don't completely see what is happeneing.

Comment: Matha is having some problem man.